# ActiveMQ 5.11.2 SchedlerSupport KahaDB Never empties

Tags: java, activemq-classic

### Overview

Running ActiveMQ 5.11.2 in a "failover" setup (just a broker to broker connection, no HA shared persistence). We're running KahaDB as the persistence with filtered kahadb to separate DLQ and other queues to different stores. Scheduler apparently does not adhere to these settings. Below is the TRACE logging [1] from the gc for the kahadb that the scheduler items reside in. There are no references to `after dest` as mentioned in http://activemq.apache.org/why-do-kahadb-log-files-remain-after-cleanup.html so it's quite hard to determine what's causing the db not to be cleaned up. All my queues are currently empty, the store percent usage on JMX should show close to 90% usage (based on the size of the DB on disk) but it shows only 30%. It doesn't appear the Scheduler KahaDB is taking in to consideration when showing this number.

**Questions**:

1. How can I force a cleanup on a kahaDB?
2. How can I get more information (either on JMX or the web UI) on what's blocked in scheduler?
3. How can I setup a real kahadb setting for the scheduler items?
4. Is there a potential bug I'm encountering? (cannot find anything on their Jira)

**Item [1]**

```
2015-08-31 22:44:14,807 | TRACE | gc candidates after removals check: [] | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.scheduler.JobSchedulerStoreImpl | ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker
2015-08-31 22:44:14,804 | TRACE | gc candidates after reference check: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161] | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.scheduler.JobSchedulerStoreImpl | ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker
2015-08-31 22:44:14,804 | TRACE | Last update: 162:21971170, full gc candidates set: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162] | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.scheduler.JobSchedulerStoreImpl | ActiveMQ Journal Checkpoint Worker
```

Comment: Did you remove all your scheduled messages ?

Comment: All the scheduled messages have been consumed if that's what you're asking. As far as I could tell all the queue sizes are zero.